# Delete From Where In Select, will no results in the select delete anything?

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I have some `Delete` statements in a stored procedure to delete some child records in other tables, and eventually delete the ID passed to the stored procedure.

I'm concerned about what happens if one of the select statements used with the `Delete` returns nothing, will this delete anything on that table?

Example

```
DELETE FROM [tblPurchases] 
WHERE [ID] IN (SELECT [ID] FROM @PurchaseIDs)
```

Comment: Empty sets are as valid as any other kind of sets. In a set-based language, you shouldn't expect them to be treated in any special fashion.

Answer (score 4):

In the case (from your example), when `SELECT [ID] FROM @PurchaseIDs` will not return anything, nothing will be deleted from `tblPurchases` because `ID in (empty_set)` condition will not be met.

by the way - you can easily check it by yourself, for example like this:

```
declare @t1 table (ID int)

insert into @t1 (ID)
select 1
union all
select 2
union all
select 3

declare @t2 table (ID int)

insert into @t2 (ID)
select 1

delete from @t1 where ID in (select ID from @t2 where ID > 1)
select * from @t1
```

Answer (score 0):

Answer is no , nothing will be deleted.  Nothing is "in" an empty collection, so nothing will be deleted.